# ¿ Como obtener el valor auto incrementable en sql server 2012?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

Hola a todos diculpen por esta pregunta quizas sea algo inusual o absurda, pero me gustaria obtener el valor autoincrementable de una tabla.

- En MySQL es esta

  `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'nombre_db' AND TABLE_NAME = 'nombre_tabla'`
- Hice de esta forma **select MAX(id_cat) + 1 from categorias**  pero cuando trunco la tabla no funciana el query.
- hay alguna forma de obtener en SQL Server ?.

Comment: prueba con `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1;` y me comentas

Answer (score 1):

Con `IDENT_CURRENT` puedes obtener el último identity generado para una tabla, `NULL` si nunca se generó un identiy o si la tabla fue truncada.

Además tienes las funciones `IDENT_SEED` e `IDENT_INCREMENT` que devuelven el valor inicial y el incremento respectivamente.

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('esquema.tabla') as IdActual,
    IDENT_SEED('esquema.tabla') as IdInicial,
    IDENT_INCR('esquema.tabla') as Incremento;
```

De igual modo si lo que necesitas es obtener el valor de ID de un registro recién insertado lo conveniente es utilizar `SCOPE_IDENTITY` para obtener dicho valor.

```
DECLARE @UltimoID INT
INSERT INTO esquema.tabla(col1, col2) VALUES (10, 'algo');
SELECT @UltimoID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

En @UltimoID queda el ID del registro recién insertado. Nota que `SCOPE_IDENTITY` devuelve el ùltimo identity generado dentro del ámbito donde fue llamado, por eso no se especifica la tabla.

Comment: hola **Asero82**  puce este codigo en mi base de datos pero me devuelven valores 1 ;  apesar de que ya inserte siempre me optiene 1  **truncate table CATEGORIAS
--dbo= nombre de shema
--categorias = nombre tabla

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.categorias') as IdActual,
    IDENT_SEED('dbo.categorias') as IdInicial,
    IDENT_INCR('dbo.categorias') as Incremento;**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usar la función `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` que dentro de SQL Server sirve para obtener el último valor insertado dentro del mismo contexto que esta siendo utilzada

Entonces tu query debería quedar de este modo:

Si en tu tabla tienes 10 registros, la siguiente consulta te mostrará el número 10

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Si por el contrario en tu tablas tienes 10 registros y colocas al final `+1` entonces obtendrás el siguiente `id` disponible

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()+1
```